# PHP Error - "Trying to get property of non-object in"

Tags: php, mailchimp

I have the following PHP 'Subscription' script I'm using to allow users to sign up to my MailChimp list.

It works as expected (adds my email address to my MailChimp list), but I also get an error on submission.

Here is my error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in 
E:\domains\*******\subscribe.php on line 29
```

**Line 29** is : `if ($data->error){`

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$apiKey = '*********************************';
$listId = '*******************';
$double_optin=true;
$send_welcome=false;
$email_type = 'html';
$email = $_POST['email'];
//replace us2 with your actual datacenter
$submit_url = "http://us5.api.mailchimp.com/1.3/?method=listSubscribe";
$data = array(
    'email_address'=>$email,
    'apikey'=>$apiKey,
    'id' => $listId,
    'double_optin' => $double_optin,
    'send_welcome' => $send_welcome,
    'email_type' => $email_type
);
$payload = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode($payload));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$data = json_decode($result);
if ($data->error){
    echo $data->error;
} else {
    echo "Thanks. You will receive an email shortly to confirm your subscription.";
}
```

*Would it help if I also provided the HTML Form code and AJAX I'm using?*

Many thanks for any helpers with this :-)

Comment: $data is an array... What you want is to check if $result === FALSE and then if it does do: `curl_error($ch);`

Comment: Also check for there error before json_decode()

Comment: `if ($result === FALSE) {
 die('1');
} else {
 die('2');
}` When I run this, I get '2'. What does this mean?

Comment: It means the call was successful, now `var_dump(json_decode($result));` instead of `die('2');` and you will see the result

Comment: Thanks. Will try now. Stay tuned :-)

Comment: `$result` is false when there was an error, else it has the result from the server...

Comment: Using `var_dump(json_decode($result));`  I get `bool(true)` as a response.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33071/discussion-between-we0-and-michaelmcgurk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late reply, but just so anyone who see's this knows:

You're getting this error because the variable you're trying to use isn't an "object"
see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

$data in this case is an array. To anyone who uses classes and objects, be sure to start your class, or global an already started class.

eg.

```
$object = new class();
```

OR

```
global $object;
```

if $object has been declared in any included files.